# Java if statement is being ignored

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I'm making a simple app where the user clicks a button which changes a TextView to the corresponding string, but when my first if statement is fulfilled it does not go on to fulfill the following if statement which should be.

```
if (index == 0 && index > -1 && index < 5) {
  one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      index++;
      text1.setText("1");
    }
  });
```

This is my first if statement, it sets the TextView to "1", and then should add to the integer "index", this turns the index's value to "1", which should end this statement because it no longer qualify, which will begin the following if statement.

```
if (index == 1 && index > -1 && index < 5) {
  one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      text2.setText("1");
      index++;
    }
  });
```

Now because of the previous `if` statement setting the index's variable to "1" this `if` statement should begin and the previous end, but this is not the case, even though the variables no longer qualify, it doesn't stop and the next if statement does not begin. It's as though the `if` statement is being ignored.

**UPDATE.**

I fixed my problem and here's what I changed the code to:

```
one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){public void onClick(View v){
  if(index == 0){
    text1.setText("1");
    index++;
  }else if(index == 1){
    text2.setText("1");
    index++;
  }else if(index == 2){
    text3.setText("1");
    index++;
  }else if(index == 3){
    text4.setText("1");
    index++;
  }
}});
```

Comment: `if (index == 0 && index > -1 && index < 5)` is equivalent to `if (index == 0)`

Comment: problems  with basic code flow ? ... your if statment is checked only once (prolly in onCreate) not at every button click ...

Comment: `if (index == 0 && index > -1 && index < 5)` makes very little sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your `index++` statement is inside the onClick callback. So this code is not executed until the button gets clicked. By that time, your second if statement will long be executed. In other words:

Your first if statement is true, this adds an `onClick` listener to the button. Your second statement is false, this does nothing. The user clicks on the button. Now **only** the code inside that first callback is executed: `index` is increased and the text is set to "1". That is all.

[EDIT this is probably  what you want]

```
one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if ( index == 0 ) {
            index++;
            text1.setText("1");
        } else if (index == 1 ) {
            text2.setText("1");
            index++;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: but my second if statement isn't executed until "index's" variable = 1, this isn't true until the button is pressed?

Answer (score 3):

From your if statement

```
if (index == 0 && index > -1 && index < 5)
```

only

```
if (index == 0)
```

is enough

same as Second one..

```
if (index == 1)
```

Comment: Also put if condition in button's onClick() to verify condition on  every button's click..

Comment: This answer does not really solve his problem I think. The comment of user370305 is important though.

Comment: I do realize that they were kind of pointless, but i was advised to by the person giving me the task

Answer (score 3):

That's not how if statements work.  When the condition becomes false control flow does not suddenly leave the block and jump to some other if-block with a true condition.

Comment: +1 because I think you understood the question (which wasn't easy)

Comment: Jochem has this right, though - s/he also answered the right question but did so with more completeness.

Answer (score 0):

After index == 1 or index == 0 what is the relevance of the other conditions?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it doesn't work, is that the listener probably is added in "onLoad" method or in the constructor of the class.

Since your `setOnClickListener` is surrounded with a if statement, only the listener is only set if the statement is true. In your case the first statment is true, while the seccond statement is false.

This means that only the first listner is added, and everytime the button is clicked, the `text1.setText("1")` is called.

You should put your if statement inside your onClickListener, and not around the logic that sets the listener. So the following code:

```
  if (index == 0 && index > -1 && index < 5) {
        one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                index++;
                text1.setText("1");

            }
        });
```

should be

```
one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if (index == 0) {
      index++;
      // Do stuff
    } else if(index == 1) {
      index++;
      // Do stuff
    }
  });
}
```

Every time the user hits the button 'one', the onClick is called. 
Inside the onClick the statement is calculated, and the correct "Do stuff" is executed.

Comment: This will not compile. The if statement is immediately after opening the anonymous class definition.

Comment: At least keep the original indentation

Answer (score 0):

Another viable solution:

```
if ((index > -1) && (index < 5)) {
    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            text2.setText(index.toString());
            index++;
    }
});
```

-Obviously this depends on the logic you require specifically, if you do require another occurrence when index == 0, you would have to alter this format:

```
if (index == 0) {
    //Whatever you want to do here... eg:
    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            text2.setText("0");
            index++;
        }
    });
}
else if ((index > -1) && (index < 5)) {
    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            text2.setText(index.toString());
            index++;
    }
});
```

Comment: In this scenario you have a if statement surrounding your onClickListener.
isn't it better to put the if statement inside your onClickListener?